# I have doubled up Polysterene 2mm on wall insulation to make 4mm is this ok

Tags: insulation, condensation

I recently applied 2mm polystyrene insulation to my walls with thermal adhesive. I now feel that 4mm would have been better, can I apply adhesive on top of the polystyrene and then add another layer or will this cause breathability issues as I understand the walls must breathe to stop condensation.

It's just for my living room and this is what I was recommended for warmer walls. My living room is not not big enough to lose 18cm each side. I just would like to know if if put adhesive on top of the existing polystyrene will it affect the breathability.

I removed the existing wallpaper and added the 2mm of polystyrene. This is added to the finished/paint side of the wall. The paper only came in 2mm not 2cm and I just wanted to know if I add adhesive to the polystyrene on top of the existing one laid down will that cause breathability issues.

Comment: Why only 2mm? I have just pt 180mm on my walls. More details of what you need to achieve and what limitations are controlling the situation are required.

Comment: Hi Solar Mike thanks for your reply. It's just for my living room and this is what I was recommended for warmer walls. My living room is not not big enough to lose 18cm each side. I just would like to know if if put adhesive ontop of the existing polysterene will it affect the breathability

Comment: Are these outside walls?  Are you putting the insulation on the finished/paint of the wall or inside the walls?

Comment: mm or cm????????

Comment: Hi Mike, these are inside walls for my living room. I removed the existing wallpaper and added the 2mm of polysterene. This is added to the finished/paint side of the wall. The paper only came in 2mm not 2cm and I just wanted to know if I add adhesive to the polysterene untop of the existing one laid down will that cause breathability issues. Thank you for responding

Comment: @SolarMike this stuff is sold on rolls for going under wallpaper to reduce condensation.  Within limits, it works pretty well at that task, but of course doesn't do much for total heat loss. It also helps the temperature rise faster when the heating comes on, as it slows heat flow into masonry - and that's true even with cavity walls. But it's a simple decorating task, rather than a major retrofit

Comment: The question is clear enough if you've seen [the product](https://www.diy.com/departments/diall-white-insulation-roll-l-10m-w-0-5m-t-2mm/1906878_BQ.prd?storeId=1247) before. Voting to reopen

Comment: Hi Rafa, it is best to edit your question to provide more details.  I am doing it now.

Comment: Slightly surprised if that passes fire code...